# How to add custom color in @angular2-material?

Tags: angular, angular2-material

I am try to add my custom color like red and green in @angular2-material/slide-toggle. If slide-toggle is disabled so color is red and if enabled so color is green.

My component.html code here:-

```
<md-slide-toggle
      (change)="testChange($event)"
      [color]="myColor">
</md-slide-toggle>
```

My component.td code here :-

```
myColor;
testChange(event) {
  alert(event)
  if(event == true)
  {
    this.myColor = "#006400";
  }
  else
  {
    this.myColor = "#FF0000";
  }
}
```

I repeat my questions:-

1. How to add custom color in angular2 material slide-toggle?
2. If slider-toggle is disabled so color is red otherwise green.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add your own custom colour theme, then you can set `[color]='primary'` etc, the docs to create your own theme are [here](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/guides/theming.md)

Comment: I am not add custom color theme only change color.

Answer (score 0):

In your ts file if condition is wrong:

```
myColor;
testChange(event) {
  alert(event)
  if(event.checked == true)
  {
    this.myColor = "#006400";
  }
  else
  {
    this.myColor = "#FF0000";
  }
}
```

You can also try with [ngClass]="checked === true ? 'redColorClass' : 'greenColorClass'"

And set your redColorClass and greenColorClass classes in component.css to show the desired colors.

Comment: I am write in css background-color so it is work but write color = red so it does not work. I am try change color of slide-toggle only.

Comment: Then it is a little bit more complicated, as you will have to use custom theme, as Joe Keene proposed.